# How to use trig functions for very high accuracy in GMP/MPFR in Python and C?

Tags: python, c, gmp, mpfr

I need to evaluate the tangent of angles between `0` and `pi` in steps of `pi/20` with a precision of 40 digits, using `gmpy 2`. I don't think importing `pi` from numpy or the standard math library is sufficient. I need 40 digits, so 133 bits of precision. I set  `gmpy2.get_context().precision=133`

```py
from gmpy2 import mpfr
from numpy import pi

for i in range(1, 11):
    print(tan(mpfr(i*pi/20)))
```

Comment: i'm afraid you'll need to use a multiprecision mathematical `tan()` function, not the standard library one.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this seems to be a school assignment, so I'll just give you some hints about how to solve that problem.

1. There's neither `gmp_sin(3)`, `gmp_cos(3)` nor `gmp_tan(3)` in the GNU GMP library, so you'll have to implement those.  You can use a Taylor series approximation for that, you will need to calculate how many terms you'll use, in order to reduce error difference under specifications.
2. You can use `gmp_sin(3)` to guess an approximation to PI accurate enough.
3. Once you have this, getting your table should present no problem.

This is a good programming challenge for calculus students, don't hesitate on working on it, you'll be satisfied with the result, in case you get to it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `numpy.pi` because it does not have the precision you need.

Luckily, there is a `const_pi` function in `gmpy2` (https://gmpy2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mpfr.html#mpfr-functions).

> **const_pi(...)**
>
> const_pi([precision=0]) returns the constant pi using
>     the specified precision. If no precision is specified, the default
>     precision is used.